# Did anyone get a Miracast display working with a Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, display, wireless, raspbian-buster

I have tried using [miraclecast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast), which builds without problems but won't find a Miracast screen which my Windows 10 laptop has no trouble to work with.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service wpa_supplicant stop
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo miracle-wifid &
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo miracle-wifictl 
[ADD] Link: 3
[miraclectl] # select 3
link 3 selected
[miraclectl] # p2p-scan
[miraclectl] # list
  LINK INTERFACE                FRIENDLY-NAME                  MANAGED   
     3 wlan0                    <unknown>                      yes       

  LINK PEER-ID                  FRIENDLY-NAME                  CONNECTED 

 0 peers and 1 links listed.
```

Did I miss any commands? Or should I be using a different software for Miracast?

As a side note, Miracast sink (`miracle-sinkctl`) also won't work: it says "now running on link 3" as expected, but no new wireless screen becomes visible on a Windows 10 laptop. Not that I'm interested in using the Pi as a sink.