# Raspicast is unable to connect using an SSH key file

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I have installed [Raspicast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.huber.raspicast&hl=en) on my Android smartphone and tried to connect to the Raspberry using a key file. I have tried both the Linux SSH key format (`id_rsa` file) and Putty key format (`*.ppk` file), which are known to work. There is no passphrase for those files, they are both unencrypted.

Raspicast won't connect with either key file, failing with the same message:

> Unable to connect!

Anyone knows what Raspicast expects? Is there a different app for screencasting on a Raspberry that actually works?

Comment: Related question about [Miraclecast](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108696/33476)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the same problem, after digging comments in the playstore app and some trial and error on multiple formats got this:

- in raspberrypi key generated like this: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM`

this generates `/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

- the usual ssh key inject: `ssh-copy-id localhost`
- in the Raspicast App use USER: pi and Key File `id_rsa` generated previously

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am new so sorry if this doesn't help but looking at raspicast and at how someone else set it up with there android maybe you need OMXIV to help with casting?

https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-As-Chromecast-Alternative-Raspicast/

The project is probably different but it shows how they connected there android phone to there raspberry pi using raspicast! Happy travels.

Comment: Those guys are using a password for SSH. My Pi is accessible on a public IP, so I won't enable password logins on it.