# Wireless connection from RPi to screen?

Tags: hdmi, wireless

How to wirelessly cast an Raspberry Pi to a screen, e.g. Miraclecast, DisplayLink, or even w. hardware assist such as from Goovis?

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108696/33476

Answer (score -1):

Raspberry Pi computers normally run a version of Linux. And most Raspberry Pi computers can connect to the local network over WIFI wirelessly.

If such is the case, you should be able to run an application remotely and have its GUI appear on the local machine.

Consider logging in from one Raspberry Pi to another using the command:

```
ssh -X user_name@192.168.0.123
```

Substituting the name of the account on the other Raspberry Pi in place of "user_name" and substituting "192.168.0.123" with the IP address of the other Raspberry Pi.

You should now be able to start a program such as a video player on the remote machine (through the SSH session started above) and have it displayed on the local machine. The video file and the video playback application are on the remote machine. The video is being set wirelessly to the local machine where it is displayed on the local machine's desktop.

Added later...

The O.P. would like video over USB-C.  It appears the Raspberry Pi does not support video over its USB-C connections.  Consider running a VNC server on the Raspberry Pi and a VNC viewer on a computer capable of video over USBC.  There are [free](https://www.tightvnc.com/) and [commercial](https://www.realvnc.com/en/) VNC variations available.

Comment: You might find ssh does not work on some "fresh installs" of Linux.  If this is the case you may need to enable ssh or install ssh from your distribution's repository.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question. I'm trying to connect Rokid glasses to a RPi, but they have USB-C connection requiring Thunderbolt or similar capability, which RPi lacks. But I have a Goovis wireless cast, which works over WiFi and I might be able to do something like what you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: I think Thunderbolt (successor to Firewire) is an Intel / Apple proprietary format.  The Raspberry Pi (RPi) foundation (a not for profit organization) is likely not going to use any proprietary format. A quick search results in no path from video to the RPi's USBC port. Sounds like there may be HDMI to USBC adapters but $$$. You can try to setup a VLC server on the RPi and VLC on a computer w/USBC video.  But that is sooo much networking and overhead ... I'll be surprised if that can support video/motion.  I'll edit my answer ... you edit your question (to include this information).